# How to convert HWND to SDL_Window?

Tags: windows, winapi, sdl-2

I'm making an SDL2 application to draw on a separate processes window. The process doesn't use SDL but I can get the `HWND` of the process window. Is it possible to get an `SDL_Window` from the `HWND`?

Comment: Rendering onto a window you do not own is not a supported scenario. No matter the tools, libraries or frameworks you use, this isn't going to work reliably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindowFrom(my_hwnd);
```

But as noted in comments, rendering into such window may or may not work properly.